# Checking multiple values in html data attribute

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have a data attribute with multiple values (data-day="5,6,7") and I want to compare todays date with those values. Below please find the code I created but corrently it works only if i have ONE value only in the data attribute. How I can check and compare today date with the multiple values in the attribute please?

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(JQuery){
        var date = new Date();
        var getday = date.getDay();

        var show = 'today';

        jQuery(".cd-gallery ul li").each(function() {
            var running_days = JQuery(this).data('day');

            if (getday == running_days) {
                JQuery(this).addClass('today');
            }
            else {
            }
        });

    });

    </script>
    <section class="cd-gallery">
        <ul>

                <li class="mix weekends" data-day="5,6,7" >
```

Comment: `.indexOf()` instead of `==`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `split()` to turn that comma delimited string to an array, then `indexOf` to find a matching value in the array. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var getday = new Date().getDay();
    var show = 'today';

    $(".cd-gallery ul li").each(function() {
        var running_days = $(this).data('day').split(',');
        if (running_days.indexOf(getday.toString()) != -1)
            $(this).addClass('today');
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ovw8vcot/)

Note that `getDay()` returns the day of the week. Today being Friday, means it will return `5`. If you want to get the day of the month (today being `17`), use `getDate()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` the values and match against the condition you were upto

```js
   jQuery(document).ready(function(JQuery){
        var date = new Date();
        var getday = date.getDay();
        var show = 'today';

        jQuery(".cd-gallery ul li").each(function() {
            var running_days = JQuery(this).data('day');
            var arr = running_days.split(',');
            $.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
               alert(value)
          });
            
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="cd-gallery">
        <ul>

                <li class="mix weekends" data-day="5,6,7" >
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = '5,6,7'; // = JQuery(this).data('day');
var daysArray = str.split(',');
for(...) {
    ...
}
```

Or by `indexOf` as @Roy McCrossan mentioned. It's better to check the value, but. The day may need to be trimmed before comparing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(JQuery){
        var date = new Date();
        var getday = date.getDay();

        var show = 'today';

        jQuery(".cd-gallery ul li").each(function() {
            var list_item = JQuery(this);
            var running_days = JQuery(this).data('day');
            var running_days_data = new Array();
            if(running_days){
                 running_days.split(',').each(function(i,val){
                     running_days_data.push(val);
                 });
            }

            if ($.inArray(getday, running_days_data) > -1;) {
                $(list_item).addClass('today');
            }
            else {
            }
        });    
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use this selector to match the date in your data-day attribute.

```
jQuery(".cd-gallery li[data-day*=" + getday + "]").addClass("today");
```

Try this and let me know if it works for you :)